# TabHost in android

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

I am displaying 3 different websites using TabHost and TabWidget. I had a doubt about Tabhost, What if I want the Tab content i.e one of the sites to perform some search operation. Not the normal google search.Say I have class A and it takes query string, AFter hitting SEARCH button, can I redirect it to one of the tabs using Intent, making it to display the query result of the entered string?

The examples I went through say only about text views and list views but no action of any sort takes place in case of webviews other than just displaying a website. I want to know does Tabhost has any limitation to performing with webviews.